# PHP : get data from database

Tags: php, web-services

I am making a web service in php.

I want to have data from database in pagination manner.

eg : I should have **10** records based on **event_id** which i am passing in url along with **page_number** i.e **10** records on **1st** page , another **10** records on **2nd** page, and so on.

I am very new to web service.

```html
<?php
http://localhost/Mobile%20Webservice/customAppEngine/faq.php?Faq_request={"faq_event_id":"302","page_number":"1"}

if(isset($_REQUEST["Faq_request"]) && trim($_REQUEST["Faq_request"]) != '') {
    $faq_details_Request = $_REQUEST["Faq_request"];
  //  $page_number = 1;
    $faqeventdetails_o = json_decode($faq_details_Request);

    
    if( isset($faqeventdetails_o->faq_event_id))
    {
        // event_id
        $event_id = $faqeventdetails_o->faq_event_id;


        if(trim($event_id)==''){
            die($msgobj->customFailMessage("Please provide Event Id"));
        }

        $userQuery="SELECT * FROM `faq` WHERE faq_event_id=$event_id";

        $u=mysql_query($userQuery);
        $number=mysql_num_rows($u);

      /*  if($number>0){
            $query="DELETE FROM `agendaLikes` WHERE event_id=$event_id and user_id=$user_id 
  and agenda_id=$agenda_id";
            mysql_query($query);
            mysql_query("UPDATE agenda SET agendaLikes=agendaLikes-1 where agenda_id=$agenda_id");


            $arr['isLike']=0;
        }else{
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `agendaLikes`(agenda_id,user_id,event_id) VALUES($agenda_id,$user_id,$event_id)");
            $arr['isLike']=1;
            mysql_query("UPDATE agenda SET agendaLikes=agendaLikes+1 where agenda_id=$agenda_id");
        }*/

        $arr['status']=$msgobj->success;

        echo json_encode($u);

    }
    else {
        die($msgobj->customFailMessage($msgobj->missingparamater));
    }
}
else {
    die($msgobj->customFailMessage($msgobj->invalidparamater));
}
```

based on `faq_event_id` i should get data.

when i hit in url then nothing is displayed.

where m I lacking?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Offset And Limit in your sql query
let's say you want 10 records for each page then you need to pass page parameter.
so for Example

`$page = 2; //parameter pass by get or post method
 $limit = 10 //our limit to get data per page 
$offset = $page*$limit; //calculate your offset`

Then your sql will look like

> $userQuery="SELECT * FROM `faq` WHERE faq_event_id=$event_id ORDER BY id LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offeset";

Hope this works for you.

Comment: `OFFSET` Starts with `0` so I have to write `($page-1)*$limit;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as well.

    `//Need to set this variable when you send request to get next 10 records, default value would be 1
    $page=1;
    $offset = 10;
    $limit = ($page - 1) * 10;
    $userQuery="$userQuery="SELECT * FROM faq WHERE faq_event_id=$event_id ORDER BY id";
    if($page > 0)
        $userQuery .= " limit $limit, $offset";`